# The output of the below code should be in green color, for h2 tag but it in normal black , Why?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-directives, ng-class

Angular Code Green color not appearing

**app.component.css**

```
.text-success{color:green}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h2 [ngClass]='borde'>Hello World</h2>
```

#### app.component.ts

```
showColor:true
public borde={text-success:this.showColor}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set `showColor` to true. You have the type set to true, but not the value. If you change it to `showColor = true` it should work fine.